# is it possible dismiss global css button property to one button?

Tags: css, html

I am wondering I can disuse global button css style property for one button which need to be

styled its own way. is there any way to disfunction button{} style in one button?

Comment: I imagine this question involves "retracting" an already set global CSS declaration, yet I'm not sure. A language barrier does exist, too, as far as I can tell.

Comment: yes. you are right. I want to retract global css declaration for a one button. Is there any way I can acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class and add it to your button.

```
<button class='button2'>Click</button>
```

Manually set all attributes within your css file.

```
.button2{ style here... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! you can set an id or a class to the button that you want to style and write whatever style you want, e.g:

`<button id='mybutton'>Click</button>`

In you css file:

`#mybutton { you style here... }`